# How do I display the Id and the date in Angular (as my frontend) from the SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, angular, api, postman

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "recipientName": "princess",
            "recipientEmail": "princess@gmail.com",
            "senderName": "kira",
            "senderEmail": "kira@gmail.com",
            "dedication": "",
            "voucher": "3000",
            "orderedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "message": "",
    "errorCode": "",
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

This is what I got from POSTMAN when I tried to GET data from the database (SQL Server). This is also what displays in my frontend (Angular). However, the Id and the orderedAt is different from what is stored in database. In database, Id is a long string while orderedAt displays the right date and time.
My question is, how do I display the right data to Angular from the database? And why did these happened? Is this sort of "encryption"?

NOTE: I used VS 2019 (.NET Core) as my backend and VS Code as my frontend.

```
<tr *ngFor = "let order of orders">
        
                        <!-- <td>{{order.id}}</td> -->
                        <td>{{order.recipientName}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.recipientEmail}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.senderName}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.senderEmail}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.dedication}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.voucher}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.orderedAt}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

This is what's written in my html(in Angular) to display the data.

Comment: looks like "Id" is of type GUID in the db, are you sure its a string?

Comment: `0001-01-01T00:00:00` is `DateTime.MinValue` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=net-5.0.. Either the column in SQL was not mapped properly to the `orderedAt` property or the value in SQL is not a valid date which may have resulted in some kind of exception and the default value was assigned.

Comment: id: 375AFAF1-7F3C-4190-9484-8DB14FDBDF01
orderedAt: 2021-05-29 01:40:05.000

This is the value of id and orderedAt in my table.
Ohh yes, id is not a string. It is GUID, rather. Why is that it's shown 00000 in API?

Comment: And the orderedAt was inserted by default GETUTCDATE().

Comment: are you using SPROC to retrieve these values? or please let know how you get these values

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetOrders]
AS
 SELECT * FROM [dbo].Orders
RETURN 0

This is only what's in storedproc. I am sorry, I'm just a newbie here in .net core, angular and sql server. :D

Comment: Please make sure "Select" statement in SPROC has fields in the same order as JSON, Also check the JSON object which binds these data.